# Apache Kafka Kraft best practices and what is the preferred disk storage for the meta-data topic

Tags: linux, hard-drive, kafka, zookeeper

My question concerns the recommended disk storage for the topic `__cluster_metadata-0`  under controllers in Kraft mode.

[image: topic]

**we have two options:**

Locate the topic `__cluster_metadata-0` , on OS volume as `/var/lib/metadata`  (as part of OS disk).

example:

```
 ls -ltr /var/lib/metadata

 drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka 4096 Jan 10 14:35 __cluster_metadata-0
```

**OR**

Set dedicated disk as `sdc` with `XFS` filesystem, that will be serve only controller process for `__cluster_metadata-0`.

example:

```
df -h /dev/sdc
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc                    10G   34M   10G   1% /kraft/metadata

ls -ltr /kraft/metadata

drwxr-xr-x 2 kafka kafka 4096 Jan 10 14:35 __cluster_metadata-0
```

Apache Kafka documentation does not specify the preferred way to locate Kraft metadata topic on OS partition or create dedicated disk in order to serve the topic `__cluster_metadata-0`.

Note - about non-Kraft Kafka cluster by using zookeeper server, the best practice are clear
when using zookeeper server, documentation specifies to set dedicated disk for zookeeper (better if they `SSD` disks), but we are not sure about the Kafka Kraft controllers and if its enough to use the OS partition for `__cluster_metadata-0` topic, or should we use dedicated disk for `__cluster_metadata-0` topic?